# sorting algorithm for the following?

Tags: algorithm, graph, topological-sort

So, I am trying to solve the following problem:

http://codeforces.com/contest/510/problem/B

Comment: Please include the problem description, instead of just linking to an external site, it is an integral part of your question and the link may break over time.

Comment: That's the later part of the story. The link is working right now. Atleast someone help me. Thanks!

Comment: Now add a description of the problem as was suggested.

Comment: A link to a question is even worse than some code and a vague description of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve it this way:

1. Create a graph `G` where each vertex represents a letter from the alphabet.
2. Insert a directed edge from `v1` to `v2` into `G` iff there exist two words in the given sequence such that `w1` = `prefix v1 suffix1`, `w2` = `prefix v2 suffix2` and `w1` precedes `w2` in the given sequence. You should figure out how to make this step efficient. I believe it can be done in `O(sum over a length of each word)`
3. Return true if `G` can be sorted topologicaly.